# Tab Delimited to Comma Separated file in UNIX - One liner?

Tags: mysql, regex, unix, replace, sed

I have a tab delimited file (MySQL Out file).

I want to convert it into CSV file. I got everything working except for replacing NULLs to nothing or spaces.

What I have is : `sed -e 's/^/"/; s/$/"/; s/\t/","/g;' < file.csv > file1.csv`

How to also replace NULLs in the same line.

The following doesn't work.

```
sed -e 's/NULL//; s/^/"/; s/$/"/; s/\t/","/g;' < file.csv > file1.csv
```

Any input is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I feel duty-bound to point out that it's almost never a good idea to try and do this. People always think "Oh, it's a [CT]SV file, it's trivial to parse", and it rarely is. Literal tabs are going to be quoted, but you're converting them to commas anyway. Furthermore, existing commas in the file aren't getting quoted, so you'll end up with more fields than you should have

Comment: Could you elaborate on how it fails to remove NULLs? Maybe give a before-and-after pair? It isn't just a matter of a missing 'g', is it?

Comment: @Beta: I think you're right. You should post an answer showing the "g": `s/NULL//g`

Comment: @ Michael : Please elaborate. Will there be any problems with this approach? This is the only solution we have till MySQL implements select into outfile - dumping the out file on a server different than that of the db.

@ Beta, Dennis : It is the missing 'g'. I totally missed it. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @eff One way it can fail is if the input already has a quoted tab in it. For example, if one of the rows in your TSV is (pretend spaces are tabs) `"one two" three`, the output should be `one two,three`, but it won't be

Comment: @ Michael : Yeah I get it now. What would be your approach in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this with sed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, csv

reader = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1], 'rb'), delimiter="\t", escapechar="\\")
writer = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'wb'))
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you just forget to put the 'g'-modifier in there?

```
sed -e 's/NULL//g; s/^/"/; s/$/"/; s/\t/","/g;' < file.csv > file1.csv
```